# Can't access the values in my array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$response['ids']
```

and

```
var_dump($response['ids']);
```

gives me this result:

```
array(849) { [0]=> int(75740521) [1]=> int(148743815) [2]=> int(14135942) [3]=> int(516369973) [4]=> int(18667319)
```

So, I try to get these values using this routine:

```
$i=0;
while($i <= $nrof){ 
    $friendsid = $friends['ids'][$i];
    echo "Friend $i-id: $friendsid<br />";
    $i++;
}
```

But I get no values out of it, `$friends['ids'][$i]` is always empty.

Comment: You have quotes around the variables $i and $friendsid when you echo them, is this correct?

Comment: You are using `$response` and `$friends`... which one holds the data?

Comment: @Jrod:$response holds the data :-) That was the error indeed. Thanks!

Comment: @Petra $nrof is the result of the count() of the array

Comment: @sam yes, that is indeed correct. You can place variables inside double quotes, but not inside single quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are var_dumping `$response` but are looping over `$friends`

Comment: Thank God It's Friday!!! And thank you for hitting me with the Obvious-bat!

Answer (score 4):

try changing $friends to $response

Answer (score 2):

why do you var_dump $**response**['ids'] but, using $**friends**['ids'] in your code?

Comment: Because it is friday afternoon, I've been coding for 12 hrs a day all week, and am waaaay to tired to debug my own code :-) Thanks for the help, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

Try using a foreach instead:

```
foreach ($friends['ids'] as $key => $value)
{
    echo "Friend $key-id: $value<br />";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: I used foreach before, but switched to while() in this particular case to debug. The problem was not the iterator that I was using, but apparently the data was in $response['ids'] and I was outputting $friends['ids']

Comment: lol and I thought you just didnt post the code where $friends['ids'] = $response['ids'] and $nrof = count($friends['ids'])

Comment: Nope, just good old tiredness was the cause :-)